# I have created registration form using html 5, In which required field validation not running when scroll down and submit form

Tags: javascript, html, validation, scroll, required

Here I am sharing a sample code of my registration form, the form is quite long. I wonder when I scroll down the form to submit, the required field validation not working.
If I zoom out the browser and the form came in one shot then validation works fine.
Also, it has strange behavior, sometimes in the chrome browser it working, and checking into another`s pc with the same browser version is not working.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem, Where I am going wrong?Thank you in advance

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register_confirmation.php" name="registration" id="registration" method="POST">
         <!---------------First Name-------------- -->
         <label class="fname_lbl"><b>Name</b> </label>
         <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="fname" required="" 
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter name')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" />
         <button type="submit" class="common_btn" id="cmn_btn">submit</button>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that your form actually is working, and that it's just displaying an error message of '' (empty string) from the OnChange event parameters, so that the error message is effectively invisible?

Comment: @rlb.usa Thank you for commenting,  perhaps it is possible but i think then it should not working when I zoom out the page and then try to fill out the form.When form is displaying into one shot at that time it is working